# Why is MSE difference between LIBSVM and my codes?

Tags: machine-learning, svm, libsvm

[image]Now I used LIBSVM toolbox to solve a regression problem. However, I found a question that  the value of MSE calculated by the toolbox  was different with the value of MSE calculated by myself. Did you meet the question?
The MSE is calculated by the equation for LIBSVM. What is the meaning of "l" in the equation? In my calculation, "l" is the number of samples.

Comment: You should give far more details. E.g. what you think the formula of MSE is. Incidentally, I guess this is the source of your problem.

Comment: Thank you. I have found the reason.  In my SVR model, MSE is calculated based on normalized data. The other MSE is calculated based on anti-normalization data.

Answer (score 1):

$\bar{l}$ denotes the sample size, so it sounds like you have that right. The letter $i$ denotes which observation number of your data you're looking at. The observations $y_1, \ldots, y_{\bar{l}}$ are in the column of your data that you are trying to predict. And $f(x_1),\ldots, f(x_{\bar{l}})$ are your predictions for these data, based on the other colums. If I were you I would check that

1. your order of operations is correct(differences, squares, add them all, divide the sum),
2. your predictions are correct (are you setting a seed if you have to, are you using the right dataset, are you looking at the data transformed correctly, are you forgetting about a certain function argument, etc).

The best case scenario is if the author of the software you're using wrote the function that estimates the model, and the function that returns the predicted values. If that's the case, the code is probably right and you're just making a small mistake.

Comment: Thank you. I have found the reason.  In my SVR model, MSE is calculated based on normalized data. The other MSE is is calculated based on anti-normalization data.

Comment: @LynnSun nice there ya go